# Що означає "лайф-стайл"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, значення-слів

У попередньому питанні наводила речення із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playboy):

> ... американський чоловічий **лайф-стайл** журнал...

Що означає термін **лайф-стайл** у поданому реченні? Інформації ніде не знайшла, адже він згадується лише в означеннях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [перекладачі](http://www.m-translate.com.ua/en-uk/word-lifestyle-translation#) знаходимо, що цей термін перекладається як **стиль життя**. Це запозичене [словосполучення](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=f1v9CQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=lifestyle++%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85&source=bl&ots=xr99x3M339&sig=X0BFOOnQiIaHuLyxQ6PcrZL2kkc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj7tLr9oDcAhVyb5oKHTZ6Dl8Q6AEIYDAI#v=onepage&q=lifestyle%20%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85&f=false) виступає центром цілої низки інновацій, наприклад, *LIFESTYLE OFFICE, LIFESTYLE FITNESS*. Так само використовується цей термін у індустрії медіа, [журналістика про стиль життя (або лайфстайл-журналістика)](https://ua.ejo-online.eu/775/sfery-vysvitlennya/%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%83). 
Тому, в поданому Вами реченні можна буквально так і перекласти **американський журнал чоловічого стилю життя**.